# BootsFaces annotation throwing errors

Tags: bootsfaces

I have just started with BootsFaces and copied a showcase from the web.
I have added BootsFaces-OSP-1.0.2-dist.jar to my eclipse project with JSF 2.1
Problem I am facing is two annotations `@Size` and `@NotEmpty` is throwing error. I can guess its a setup issue, can anybody help?

Comment: Add the error message also share your project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

With so little information, I can only guess. I suppose you're referring to compiler errors. Did you add the validation API and the hibernate validator?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the complete list of jars you have to add to run our showcase:

[image]